# Raw Query works on phpmyadmin but not in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have written a raw Query in phpmyadmin which provide me exact answer.but same query when i tried to execute in Laravel..I got Error:

Raw Query:

```
SELECT customers.customer_name, customers.voucher_number ,
         services.name, customers.status,sum(carts.amount) FROM  services JOIN customers
        on services.id = customers.service_id JOIN carts on customers.id = carts.customer_id          
        GROUP BY customers.id
```

in Laravel :

```
$status_report = DB::select("SELECT customers.customer_name, customers.voucher_number ,
         services.name, customers.status,sum(carts.amount) FROM  services JOIN customers
        on services.id = customers.service_id JOIN carts on customers.id = carts.customer_id         
        GROUP BY customers.id");
```

What could be the possible Error?

I got the following Error :

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'maitree.customers.customer_name' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: SELECT customers.customer_name, customers.voucher_number ,
services.name, customers.status,sum(carts.amount) FROM services JOIN customers
on services.id = customers.service_id JOIN carts on customers.id = carts.customer_id 
GROUP BY services.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be a with [SQL_MODE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html), Please makes changes into connection "config/database.php" :

> strict => false

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It works. Just make this change then run config cache command and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `DB::raw` to wrap your raw SQL.

```
$status_report = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT customers.customer_name, customers.voucher_number ,
     services.name, customers.status,sum(carts.amount) FROM  services JOIN customers
    on services.id = customers.service_id JOIN carts on customers.id = carts.customer_id         
    GROUP BY customers.id"));
```